# Check if element has child

Tags: html, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have the following DOM tree (simplified)

```html
<div class=row-0>...</div>
<div class=row-1>
  <div class=container>
    <div class=panel>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=row-2>...</div>
<div class=row-3>
  <div class=container>
    <div class=panel>...</div>
    <div class=drawer>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=row-4>...</div>
```

As you can see, all elements have a panel `class=panel` but not all elements have a drawer `class=drawer`.
I am iterating through the elements as follows:

```js
const events = Selector('[class^="row-"]');
const eventCount = await events.count;

for (let i = 0; i < eventCount; i++) {
  const event = await events.nth(i);
  // Here's where I want to check if the event (class=row-x) has a child element class=drawer
  const drawer = await Selector(event).child('class["drawer"]')
  if (await drawer.exists) {
    console.log('Found drawer')
  }
}
```

I can successfully iterate through all the rows, but I cannot detect if a certain event has a drawer. I tried to follow the logic from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359687/testcafe-how-to-check-if-a-web-element-exists-or-does-not-exist-without-failin) answer and also from the [docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/examples-of-working-with-dom-elements.html#check-if-an-element-is-available).

How can I perform this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you rewrite your test as follows:

1. Get all "drawer" elements: `Selector('div.drawer')`.
2. Get all rows that contain the "drawer" elements according to your page hierarchy.

I have created a simple example - please check it out:

**index.html**:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class=row-0>Row 0</div>
<div class=row-1>
    Row 1
    <div class=container>
        <div class=panel>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=row-2>Row 2</div>
<div class=row-3>
    Row 3
    <div class=container>
        <div class=panel>...</div>
        <div class=drawer>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=row-4>Row 4</div>
<div class=row-5>
    Row 5
    <div class=container>
        <div class=panel>...</div>
        <div class=drawer>...</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**:

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture`
    .page `./index.html`;

test('find rows with "drawer"', async t => {
    const drawerElements = Selector('div.drawer').addCustomDOMProperties({
        outerHTML: el => el.outerHTML
    });
    const length = await drawerElements.count;

    console.log('Row elements count:', length);

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        console.log('//', i + 1, 'element:');
        console.log(await drawerElements.nth(i).parent().parent().outerHTML);
    }
});
```

Command:

```
testcafe chrome test.js
```

Result:

```
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 78.0.3904 / Windows 10.0.0

 Fixture
Row elements count: 2
// 1 element:
<div class="row-3">
    Row 3
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel">...</div>
        <div class="drawer">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
// 2 element:
<div class="row-5">
    Row 5
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel">...</div>
        <div class="drawer">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
 √ find rows with "drawer"


 1 passed (1s)
```